# Filter Array of Objects based on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I want to filter my data based on checkboxes checked.

I have 3 checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="shoes" value="shoes" class="storesCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="clothes" value="clothes" class="storesCheckBox" />
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="sports" class="storesCheckBox" />
```

and my stores data is

```
// my stores
var stores = [
    {
        id: 1,
        store: 'Store 1',
        storeType: "shoes"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        store: 'Store 2',
        storeType: "clothes"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        store: 'Store 3',
        storeType: "sports"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        store: 'Store 3',
        storeSells: "shoes"
    }
]
```

So, If I check `shoes` checkbox, I want to filter the data based on storeType `shoes`. So I wrote

```
var getStores = stores.filter(function (store) {
    return store.storeType === 'shoes';
});
```

But Now, if I check `clothes` and `shoes` is already checked. I want to filter `shoes + clothes` data. And If I uncheck, `shoes` again I want to filter only clothes data. It can be any number of checkboxes depending on the store type. can you please help me out with this?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes! sorry I will fix it.

Comment: store your conditions into an array, then in the `filter` use `includes` method.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var storeTypesSelected; //array of the types checked
var getStores = stores.filter(function (store) {
    return storeTypesSelected.indexOf(store.storeType) > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the checked checkboxes, construct an array (or Set) of the selected values. Then, when iterating over the array, check whether the current `storeType` is included in the collection:

```js
var stores = [{
    id: 1,
    store: 'Store 1',
    storeType: "shoes"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    store: 'Store 2',
    storeType: "clothes"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    store: 'Store 3',
    storeType: "sports"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    store: 'Store 3',
    storeType: "shoes"
  }
];

document.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const checkedValues = [...document.querySelectorAll('.storesCheckBox')]
    .filter(input => input.checked)
    .map(input => input.value);
  const filteredStores = stores.filter(({ storeType }) => checkedValues.includes(storeType));
  console.log(filteredStores);
});
```

```html
Shoes: <input type="checkbox" name="shoes" value="shoes" class="storesCheckBox" />
Clothes: <input type="checkbox" name="clothes" value="clothes" class="storesCheckBox" />
Sports: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="sports" class="storesCheckBox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to hold the checkbox values for filtering in an array.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("storesCheckBox");
var list = [];
for(var i=0; elems[i]; ++i){
      if(elems[i].checked){
           list.push(elems[i].value);
      }
}
var getStores = stores.filter(function (store) {
    return list.indexOf(store.storeType) >= 0;
});
```

The return statement will do the filtering with indexOf function.