# Javascript filter sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

Help with modifying the code so I can sort by more than one filter. As an example, I'd like to be able to "check" BOTH Blue and Green, and have the result show two items. My code would work like that IF there is both 'blue green' in the data-colors area.

I know very little JavaScript, so any help would be appreciated!

```js
const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function updateFilter() {
  const checkedValues = Array.from(filterCheckboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

  filterables.forEach(filterable => {
    const colors = filterable.dataset.colors.split(' ');
    if (checkedValues.every(value => colors.includes(value))) {
      filterable.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      filterable.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Color</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="blue">Content 1</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="green">Content 2</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="red">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd consider searching for "js filter by two conditions" (or sort, etc) as a decent starting point, maybe with "site:stackoverflow.com" for more specificity.

Comment: just `some` instead of `every`? But definitely a duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Array of Objects based on checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796024/filter-array-of-objects-based-on-checkboxes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated yours to include @pilchard suggestion and a clunky reset of the list.

It needed to utilize `some` instead of `every`, then you need to reset you list if no filter was selected.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h3>Color</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
    </div>
   <div>
       <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
<div class="filterable" data-colors="blue">Blue Content 1</div>
<div class="filterable" data-colors="green">Green Content 2</div>
<div class="filterable" data-colors="red">Red Content 3</div>
</div> 
    <script>
    const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function updateFilter() {
  const checkedValues = Array.from(filterCheckboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);
  
    if (!checkedValues.length > 0) {  
      filterables.forEach(filterable => {
        filterable.style.display = 'block';
      })
    return;
  }

  filterables.forEach(filterable => {
    const colors = filterable.dataset.colors.split(' ');
    if (checkedValues.some(value => colors.includes(value))) {
      filterable.style.display = 'block';
    } else {      
      filterable.style.display = 'none';
    }    
  });
  

}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the call `filterables.forEach(...)`, making the following in the if condition change solves the problem.
Change:

```
checkedValues.every(value => colors.includes(value))
```

To:

```
checkedValues.some(value => colors.includes(value)) || checkedValues.length === 0
```

```js
const filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-checkbox');
const filterables = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable');

function updateFilter() {
  const checkedValues = Array.from(filterCheckboxes)
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
    .map(checkbox => checkbox.value);

  filterables.forEach(filterable => {
    const colors = filterable.dataset.colors.split(' ');
    if (checkedValues.some(value => colors.includes(value)) || checkedValues.length === 0) {
      filterable.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      filterable.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateFilter);
});

updateFilter(); // initial filter based on default checkbox state
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Color</h3>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="blue">Blue</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="green">Green</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter-checkbox" value="red">Red</label>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Filtered Result</h1>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="blue">Content 1</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="green">Content 2</div>
  <div class="filterable" data-colors="red">Content 3</div>
</div>
```